# How to remove the light color on input which be selected in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

If you use chrome browser, please click **Run code snippet** and you will find there is a light blue color around the input, I want to remove it. 
I have tried `border:none` and `:active` and other pseudo class. But it is not worked.
By the way, in FF. The light color isn't exist.

```html
    <input type="text">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use this;

```
   input:focus{
        outline: 0;
    }
```

Or to remove from all elements

```
*:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The key is **outline**.

Comment: Make it after 4 minutes.